# static field not changed?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm new to C# , just a question on static field.
Let's say we have the following class:

```
 class SavingsAccount
    {
        public double currBalance;

        // A static point of data.
        public static double currInterestRate = 0.04;

        public SavingsAccount(double balance)
        {
            currBalance = balance;
        }

        // Static members to get/set interest rate.
        public void SetInterestRate(double newRate)
        { 
            currInterestRate = newRate; 
        }

        public static double GetInterestRate()
        { 
            return currInterestRate; 
        }
    }
...
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SavingsAccount s1 = new SavingsAccount(50);
            Console.WriteLine("Interest Rate is: {0}", SavingsAccount.GetInterestRate());
            s1.SetInterestRate(0.09);
            SavingsAccount s2 = new SavingsAccount(100);
            Console.WriteLine("Interest Rate is: {0}", SavingsAccount.GetInterestRate());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

and the output is:

```
Interest Rate is: 0.04
Interest Rate is: 0.09
```

I understand static field apply in class-level, but when we create s2:

```
SavingsAccount s2 = new SavingsAccount(100);
```

isn't that `public static double currInterestRate = 0.04;` reset currInterestRate  back to 0.04? why is 0.09? what does CLR do to make it not reset?

Comment: _"public void SetInterestRate(double newRate)"_ is not a _"// Static members ..."_ - it is an instance member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> isn't that public static double currInterestRate = 0.04; reset currInterestRate back to 0.04?

No, static fields belong to *class scope*. So, no matter you create how many `SavingsAccount` objects, there is only one `currInterestRate` ever existed.

Note that, when you create a new `SavingsAccount` object, the instance fields are initialized, then the constructor is executed, but the static fields are untouched. Please don't think that the whole code segment outside the methods is executed.